# Slim template include link tag in option tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I am trying to have a dropdown (not part of a form) input where each `option` tag is a link to a controller action.

I've tried various ways of included it but nothing works

```
SELECT NAME="my-dropdown"
        OPTION VALUE="1111" steam turbine
        = link_to 'Action', path(my_action), class: 'nav-link'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @Eyeslandic, you can do your stuff like this in slim :

```
select name="my-dropdown" onchange="location = this.value;"
  option value="#{url_for 'Action', my_action_path}" class="nav-link"
    | steam turbine
```

You can take a look at these websites to help you to write in slim :

- [slim to html](https://tools.gizipp.com/slim-to-html-erb)
- [html to slim](https://html2slim.herokuapp.com/)